# Is it possible to use ducts with a window a/c unit?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I'm trying to cool my home recording studio, but my window a/c unit is far too loud. I have a closet in the room which has a window and I was wondering if/how I could use ducts to put the a/c in the closet window and pipe it out into the room with the use of some 90 degree angle joint things.

The room is 12ftx12ft. The closet is 3.5ftx3ft.

This is the closet and an arrow to the window. The window inside is perpendicular to the room:

[image]

This is the window (it's bigger once opened) with the duct idea:

[image]

Then I was thinking of cutting 2 holes in the closet door for the vents and keeping the door shut to cut down on noise:

[image]

I'm not very concerned with 100% efficiency as long as it will cool the room a bit while being quieter. Unfortunately, I can't install a mini-split or central.

Comment: move the AC to the closet window and run it just to see if the noise level is actually acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add ductwork to a room air conditioner, but be careful, 1) not to restrict the “air volume”, 2) allow for friction loss, and 3) use fewest number of turns as possible.

We use “duct silencers” to reduce the noise from fans in ductwork. See this:

https://www.acousticalsurfaces.com/hvac/duct_silen.htm

They are expensive, but you could make your own. The principle is that you want the air to go around a few baffles so the noise gets trapped in the acoustic panels inside the ductwork.

Make sure you oversize the ductwork.

Comment: Making sure to use large duct work will be important+